# Paypal old programmer missing old sandbox

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I have old Sandbox business & personal accounts that stopped working. I have to go back and test a site I developed two years ago. I saw a reference to importing these accounts on the new site but every link seems to go in circles. I certainly can't afford time to rewrite all my client's api's even if they would pay me just to go into testing mode.
Can someone suggest how I might revive these accounts.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently some issues that are being addressed to resolve this issue.  As a workaround try using FireFox or Chrome if you were using IE.  Clear your cookies and chache prior to opening up that browhwer.  Then go to developer.paypal.com and log in with your live PayPal account email address.  Then try importing your accounts.  There have been more issues with IE than the other browsers.

Comment: Ok perfect now it's working now. I had logged in ok but before when I clicked on Looking for Sandbox it took me to the old X site. Any thank you all is good. (fyi: I normally develop with Firefox with the cache off anyway.)